# How can I use multiple if statement inside another if statement of a awk program?

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv

I have a CSV File and I want to have multiple checks to retrieve the data from the CSV file. I have the following conditions which needs to be taken care of and I am trying to use awk in a shell script to fulfill these conditions:

```
if ( ColD == "TRX" || ColD == "TX" )
{
   if (ColJ == "BTS INT UNAFF" || ColJ == "LOCAL MODE")
   {
      if (ColL !="OPER" && ColL != "") #Second Value shouldn't be blank
      {
         if (ColU != "2000")
         {
             if (ColA != "*_*") # Should not contain _ in the value.
             then
                   print all the resulting filtered columns of this csv file
```

Here ColA, ColB etc. are the column numbers which i use as $1, $2 and so on.

Now I know simple awk usage of a single if condition is something like this:

```
awk -F, '{
                if ($23 == "TOP36")
                print $11
            }' $INPUT_PATH/$fileName
```

and could find the nested if conditions something like this:

```
awk '
{if ( $6 == 0 && $8 > 0 && $8 <= 9 ) { $6 = "left" } else {
  if ( $8 == 0 && $6 > 0 && $6 <= 15 ) { $6 = "bottom" } else {
    if ( $8 == 9 && $6 > 0 && $6 <= 15 { $6 = "top" } else {
      if ( $6 == 15 && $8 > 0 && $8 <= 9 { $6 = "right" }
      }
    }
  }
} {print}'
```

But, I think my conditions can be satisfied if I put satisfy one if condition on top and then next under it and so on. How can I do it using awk if statements? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested *`if` statements* are effectively  *statement `and` statement*,  so if you do not need to do any particular processing as you step through the nesting, then you can just join them all up with `&&`.

```
  awk '{ if( ( $4 == "TRX" || $4 == "TX" ) &&
             ( $10 == "BTS INT UNAFF" || $10 == "LOCAL MODE" ) && 
             ( $12 != "OPER" && $12 != "" ) && # Second Value should not be blank
             ( $22 != "2000") &&
             ( !match( $1, "_") ) ) # Should not contain _ in the value.
           { print } 
       }' FS=, file
```

To define your Field Separator, you can use *option `-F,`* instead of *parameter `FS=,`* if you prefer – or have it fully contained within the `awk` code, in the `BEGIN{ }` pre-file-processing block: `BEGIN{ FS="," }`

Comment: And if the only action is `print`, then you can use just `awk FS=, '($4 == "TRX" || $4 == "TX") && … && !match($1, "_")'`

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary and Gilles for your inputs. I will try this. One more question here, in the last condition, (!match $1, "-")  Is this going to ignore all the values in column 1 where value conatins a _ ex: BTS_101, BSC_505 etc?  and the hopefully the last print statement prints the entire CSV file data after filtering all the above conditions in the input CSV file?